# emulate SAS' datastep statement FIRST using linux command line tools

Tags: command-line

Let's say I have the first column of the following dataset in a file and I want to emulate the flag in the second column so I export only that row tied to a flag = 1 (dataset is pre-sorted by the target column):

```
 1 1
 1 0
 1 0
 2 1
 2 0
 2 0
```

I could run `awk 'NR==1 {print; next} seen[$1]++ {print}' dataset` but would run into a problem for very large files (`seen` keeps growing). Is there an alternative to handle this without tracking every single unique value of the target column (here column #1)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you only have the first column? And would like to generate the second? I think a slightly different awk command could work

```
awk '{if (last==$1) {flag=0} else {last=$1; flag=1}; print $0,flag}' file.txt
```

Basically you just check if the first field matches the last one you've seen. Since it's sorted, you don't have to keep track of everything you've seen, only the last one to know if the value is different.

Comment: Simple, straighforward solution, thanks. My data had missings in $1, and so I had to initialize last to -1: `if (NR==1) {last=-1} ...`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like grep would be fine for this:

```
$ grep " 1" dataset
```